# Python check if string got a certain word (or combination of characters)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok so I have this string (for example):

```
var = "I eat breakfast."
```

What i would like to do is to check if that string contains "ea".

Comment: Show your effort - what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
>>> var = "I eat breakfast."
>>> 'ea' in var
True
```

I'm not clear what you mean by "put those values into a list." I assume you mean the words:

```
>>> [w for w in var.split() if 'ea' in w]
['eat', 'breakfast.']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `word in sentence`. For example:

```
>>> 'el' in 'Hello'
True
>>> 'xy' in 'Hello'
False
```

For your reference, check: [python `in` operator use cases](http://kracekumar.com/post/22512660850/python-in-operator-use-cases)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [Finding multiple occurrences of a string within a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python#3873422)

You can use `find(str, startIndex)` like so:

```
var = "I eat breakfast."

locations = []
index = 0
while index < len(var):
  index = var.find('ea', index)
  if index == -1:
    break
  locations.append(index)
  index += 2
```

`locations` is a list of the indices where `'ea'` was found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to check if a string contains a substring. It also sounds like you want to add `var` to a list if it contains a substring. Observe the following interactive session:

```
In [1]: var = "I eat breakfast."

In [2]: lst = []

In [3]: if "ea" in var:
   ...:     lst.append(var)
   ...:     

In [4]: lst
Out[4]: ['I eat breakfast.']
```