# Finding the items in a list in a string

Tags: python

```
def finding_letters(s,l):

    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        l = ''.join(l[i])
        a = s.find(l[i])
        return a
    i = i + 1
```

calling

```
finding_letters('abcde',['ab','cd','e'])
```

should give me an output of `0,2,4`, but I only get output of `0`.

Anything I could do to fix this?

Comment: please don´t use the facebook tag if it is not about facebook stuff. tag the programming language, for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding multiple occurrences of a string within a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I'n not 100% sure what it is exactly that you're trying to do, but if you're trying to find the index of s where an element of l begins, here's one way.

```
s = 'abcde'
l = ['ab','cd','e']
l = [i[0] for i in l if i in s] #get the first letter of an element of l, but only if that element can be found in s 
output = [list(s).index(i) for i in l] #get the index of s where that element can be found 
print(output)                           
[0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

A simple generator approach can be used here:

```
>>> def find_letters(seq, l):
        for el in l:
            if not seq.find(el) == -1:
                yield seq.find(el)


>>> find_letters('abcde',['ab','cd','e'])
<generator object find_letters at 0x04305510>
>>> list(find_letters('abcde',['ab','cd','e']))
[0, 2, 4]
>>>
```

Or better yet, a simpler generator expression:

```
>>> list(('abcde'.find(el) for el in ['ab','cd','e'] if 'abcde'.find(el) != -1))
[0, 2, 4]
>>>
```