# match multiple str in list python

Tags: python, string, match

all

```
a = ['T01--X','T02--X','T03--X','T04--XX','T01--X','T01--Y','T05--X','T02-YY','T01-T02','T02-T03']
```

how to match str including T01 or T02 or T03 in this list?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected output? A boolean? A string? All list items that matches with any of three? More importantly, what have you tried?

Comment: What are your criteria for matching?

Comment: you can get help from this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ['T01--X','T02--X','T03--X','T04--XX','T01--X','T01--Y','T05--X','T02-YY','T01-T02','T02-T03']

for i in a:
    if 'T01' in i or 'T02' in i or 'T03' in i :
        print(i)
```

out:

```
T01--X
T02--X
T03--X
T01--X
T01--Y
T02-YY
T01-T02
T02-T03
```

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Using simple `for` and `if` loop.

```
a = ['T01--X','T02--X','T03--X','T04--XX','T01--X','T01--Y','T05--X','T02-YY','T01-T02','T02-T03']

result = []
for element in a:
     if 'T01' in element or 'T02' in element or 'T03' in element :
             result.append(element)
print result
```

### Method 2

Using list comprehension. A more pythonic way!

```
a = ['T01--X','T02--X','T03--X','T04--XX','T01--X','T01--Y','T05--X','T02-YY','T01-T02','T02-T03']
print [elt for elt in a if 'T01' in elt or 'T02' in elt or 'T03' in elt]
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: `if 'T01' in element or 'T02' in element or 'T03' in element` could be reduced to `if element in ('T01', 'T02', 'T03')`.

Comment: @leaf Are you sure? The logic seems reversed for me! Your code will search for element which is same as 'T01' or 'T02' or 'T03'. But it doesn't look like, it will find sub string. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Actual, your right. My example above will not work. I forgot to cut the first three characters from `element`. **This will work however**: `if element[0:3] in ('T01', 'T02', 'T03')`. For more info behind this see [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values).

Comment: Yeah! Your method works great when checking **equality**, I suppose! Still for checking sub string, I prefer basic ```if``` statement with many ```or``` and/or ```and```. I would also prefer using ```any``` method, as MSeifert used here!

Anyway thanks @leaf, I learned a new way on checking equality.

Comment: Python & function-ish: `result = [i for i in a if any(map(lambda x: x in i, ['T01', 'T02', 'T03']))]` |OR| 
`result = list(filter(lambda i: any([x in i for x in ('T01', 'T02', 'T03',)]), a))`

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like a conditional list comprehension?

In that case you could use:

```
>>> [item for item in a if any(substr in item for substr in ['T01', 'T02', 'T03'])]
['T01--X', 'T02--X', 'T03--X', 'T01--X', 'T01--Y', 'T02-YY', 'T01-T02', 'T02-T03']
```

Comment: I really don't think we should be answering questions which are so ambiguous.

Comment: @leaf I don't think the question is ambiguous and when in doubt I rather answer a question (if I can) than to overthink the issue.

Comment: @leaf sorry to make the confusion.I am newbie to python and Stackoverflow