# why will .index only pick up the first use of a repeated word

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and i just cannot figure out why my code only displays the first use of the word.If someone could suggest a quick and easy way that it would display both then that would be greatly appreciated.

```
sentence = input("please insert a sentence").lower()
keyword = input ("please insert a keyword you would like to search for")
splitsentence = sentence.split(" ")
position = sentence.index(keyword)
if keyword in sentence:
    print(position)
```

Comment: Because that's what the `index` function is meant to do.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: this is not a list, but a string and it is a *substring*... But probably there is a dupe somewhere.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You're right, was fooled because the OP makes a list but dosen't use it, perhaps this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 1):

That's how [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.index) is designed; to only return the first occurrence.

If you want to find all occurrences, you must call it multiple times in a loop or with recursion. Before we do that, you should know that you can provide `start` and `end` parameters to define where to search in the sentence:

```
>>> "cat cat".index("cat")
0
>>> "cat cat".index("cat", 1)  # start search from index 1
4
>>> "cat cat".index("cat", 1, 4)  # ...and stop search right before index 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

This way we can avoid getting the same index all the time in our loop:

```
s = "cat cat"
indexes = []

index = -1
while True:
    try:
        index = s.index("cat", index + 1)
    except ValueError:
        break
    indexes.append(index)

print(indexes)
# Output: [0, 4]
```

Here's a recursive generator if you want to go fancy:

```
def find_indices(s, sub, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(s)
    try:
        start = s.index(sub, start, end)
    except ValueError:
        return
    yield start
    yield from find_all_indexes(s, sub, start + 1, end)
```

Usage (also still supports `start` and `end` arguments):

```
>>> list(find_indices("cat cat cat cat", "cat"))
[0, 4, 8, 12]
```

Or if you want a non-recursive generator, you could use the original `while` loop and have it `yield` instead of append to a list:

```
def find_indices(s, sub, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(s)
    start -= 1
    while True:
        try:
            start = s.index(sub, start + 1, end)
        except ValueError:
            break
        yield start
```

Exact same usage as before.

Answer (score 0):

Because that is how `.index` is defined: the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.index#str.index) says:

> **`str.index(sub[, start[, end]])`**
>
> Like
>   [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.index#str.find),
>   but raise `ValueError` when the substring is not found.

and [`.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.index#str.find):

> **`str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`**
>
> Return the **lowest index** in the string where substring sub is found
>   within the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments start and end are
>   interpreted as in slice notation. Return `-1` if sub is not found.

(highlighting added)

An idea to find **all** indices is to use:

```
[i for i in range(len(sentence)) if keyword == sentence[i:i+len(keyword)]]
```

Or perhaps more efficient: a generator that generates indices:

```
def find_indices(sentence,keyword):
    idx = -1
    while True:
        idx = sentence.find(keyword,idx+1)
        if idx < 0:
            break
        yield idx
```