# Python regex of multiple occurrences of a string of 1+ consecutive chars within a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to find starting and ending positions of variable length sequences of chars, consisting of same 1 letter inside a string.
I saw this topic [Finding multiple occurrences of a string within a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python), but I assume it's a bit off.

The following gives me nothing, while I expect to have 5 elements found.

```
import re
s = 'aaaaabaaaabaaabaaba'
pattern = '(a)\1+'
for el in re.finditer(pattern, s):
    print 'str found', el.start(), el.end()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [It works well, just use a **raw string literal**](https://ideone.com/SxWJdh). And you can only expect 4 results. Else, replace the `+` with `*`.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew,  thank you, esp for a tip about *.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since it is a regex, the backslash should *not* be escaped at the string level, but should be interpreted by the regex.

You can use a raw string:

```
import re
s = 'aaaaabaaaabaaabaaba'
pattern = r'(a)\1+'   # raw string
for el in re.finditer(pattern, s):
    print 'str found', el.start(), el.end()
```

This generates:

```
str found 0 5
str found 6 10
str found 11 14
str found 15 17
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Marked as accepted.