# match all occurrence of regular

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract all occurrences of a pattern in Python.
Here is what i have done

```
import re

string="Any information <p>sent to the server as clear text</p>, may be stolen and used later for <p>identity theft</p> or user impersonation. In addition, several privacy regulations state that sensitive information such as user<p> credentials will always be sent encrypted </p> to the web site."

regex='<p>.*</p>' # obviously it matches starting <p> to the last </p>

if re.findall(regex, String):
    print(re.findall(regex, string))
else:
    print('no match found')
```

I want to extract all the occurance of paragraph tags. I mean the output should be a list which looks like this

```
['<p>sent to the server as clear text</p>', '<p>identity theft</p>', '<p> credentials will always be sent encrypted </p>']
```

I've found few similar questions but not serving the purpose
[Find all occurrences of a substring in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python)

[Finding multiple occurrences of a string within a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python)

Comment: The first failure source is often the regex, you can check it here 
 https://regex101.com/

Comment: Do not use `re.findall` twice. Use `res = re.findall(...)` and then display the message you want after checking `res` length.

Comment: Got the answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop

Making .* non-greedy did the trick.. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `regex` like this :

```
regex=r"<p>.*?</p>"
```

It gives o/p like :

```
['<p>sent to the server as clear text</p>', '<p>identity theft</p>', 
 '<p> credentials will always be sent encrypted </p>']
```

Comment: this is the exact regex.
regex='<p>.*?<\/p>'