# Substring with multiple instances of the same character

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I am using a Magtek USB reader that will read card information,

As of right now I can swipe a card and I get a long string of information that goes into a Tkinter Entry textbox that looks like this

```
%B8954756016548963^LAST/FIRST INITIAL^180912345678912345678901234?;8954756016548963=180912345678912345678901234?
```

**All of the data has been randomized, but that's the format**

I've got a tkinter button (it gets the text from the entry box **in the format I included above** and runs this)

```
    def printCD(self):
        print(self.carddata.get())
        self.card_data_get = self.carddata.get()
        self.creditnumber = 
        self.card_data_get[self.card_data_get.find("B")+1:
        self.card_data_get.find("^")]
        print(self.creditnumber)
        print(self.card_data_get.count("^"))
```

**This outputs:**

```
%B8954756016548963^LAST/FIRST INITIAL^180912345678912345678901234?;8954756016548963=180912345678912345678901234?
8954756016548963
```

This yields no issues, but if I wanted to get the next two variables firstname, and lastname

I would need to reuse self.variable.find("^") because in the **format** it's used before **LAST** and after **INITIAL**

So far when I've tried to do this it hasn't been able to reuse "^"

Any takers on how I can split that string of text up into individual variables:

**Card Number**

**First Name**

**Last Name**

**Expiration Date**

Comment: So there's two lines there, stack made it hard to format it, 
it pulls the text from "B" to "^" (which is continued on the next line) 
and saves it to the variable self.creditnumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex will work for this. I didn't capture everything because you didn't detail what's what but here's an example of capturing the name:

```
import re
data = "%B8954756016548963^LAST/FIRST INITIAL^180912345678912345678901234?;8954756016548963=180912345678912345678901234?"

matches = re.search(r"\^(?P<name>.+)\^", data)

print(matches.group('name'))
# LAST/FIRST INITIAL
```

If you aren't familiar with regex, here's a way of testing pattern matching: https://regex101.com/r/lAARCP/1 and an intro tutorial: https://regexone.com/

But basically, I'm searching for (one or more of anything with .+ between two carrots, ^).

Actually, since you mentioned having first and last separate, you'd use this regex:

```
\^(?P<last>.+)/(?P<first>.+)\^
```

This question may also interest you regarding finding something twice: [Finding multiple occurrences of a string within a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Sorry if my question was complicated or not explained well enough, you've given me the resources I need!

Comment: @JakeWenzel No problem! The question was fine. I just couldn't quickly spot the expiration date. If you feel the question is answered, please be sure to select one of the answers.

Comment: @Zev absolutely, so real quick, if I wanted to reference from "^" to "/" for last name and then "/" to "^" for first name I would just use `\^(?P<last>.+)/(?P<first>.+)\^` ?

Comment: Yes! Give it a try and let me know if you have any trouble. You'd access them as `matches.group('last')` or `matches.group('first')`

Comment: So it worked, I'm having a hard time doing this with the credit card number though.

`re.search(r"\d(?P<creditcard>.+)\^`

It automatically goes to the second '^'

Comment: So instead of creditcard being 8954756016548963 it is 8954756016548963^LAST/FIRST INITIAL

Comment: You can find all the groups at once (like @PatrickArtner showed) or modify your query to be `\d(?P<creditcard>.+)\^.+\^` so it looks for numbers before two carrots rather than just one.

Answer (score 0):

If you find regex difficult you can divide the problem into smaller pieces and attack one at a time:

```
data = '%B8954756016548963^LAST/FIRST INITIAL^180912345678912345678901234?;8954756016548963=180912345678912345678901234?'

pieces = data.split('^')    # Divide in pieces, one of which contains name

for piece in pieces:
    if '/' in piece:
        last, the_rest = piece.split('/')
        first, initial = the_rest.split()
        print('Name:', first, initial, last)
    elif piece.startswith('%B'):
        print('Card no:', piece[2:])
```

Comment: Thank you for this as well! I will try and re-learn regex and then try this.