# How can I index multiple spaces in a given string?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, indexing

I tried to map the index where spaces are provided in a given string. But the problem was I couldn't find the index of multiple spaces. Only the first space index was shown.

This is my sample explanation:

```
Y="Hell o World!"
print(Y.index(" "))
```

```
Output: 4
```

I'm not able to map the space on index: 6

Comment: ```index``` only returns the first instance of the substring. You can do ```[i for i,j in enumerate(Y) if j==' ']```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883980/find-the-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string) they discussed the issue. Maybe one of those solutions is fitting for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the nth occurrence of substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883980/find-the-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding multiple occurrences of a string within a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:
According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=index#str.index)

> `str.index` is like `find()`, but raise `ValueError` when the substring is not found.

And for `find()`

> Return the ***lowest index*** in the string where substring sub is found within the slice `s[start:end]`

In your string, `4` is the first or the lowest index where python found a space: `' '`

```
>>> Y="Hell o World!"
>>> [i for i,j in enumerate(Y) if j==' ']
[4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
Y = "Hell o World"
occurences_list = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(' ', Y)]

print(occurences_list) # [4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom function and `yield` :

```
def findall(text, pattern):
    '''Yields all the positions of the pattern in the text.'''
    i = text.find(pattern)
    while i != -1:
        yield i
        i = text.find(pattern, i+1)

Y = "Hell o World"
print(list(findall(Y, ' ')) # [4, 6]
```