# Rewriting a string and removing unwanted elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use the python library Nvdlib which aims to extract information from Nist. Among these informations, I'm interested in the CPE and especially the api output.
Here is my code :

```
import nvdlib
r = nvdlib.searchCVE(cveId='CVE-2019-19781')[0]

conf = r.configurations #list in ouput

for x in conf:
     txt = ', '.join(str(x) for x in x.nodes) #transforme list to string
     print(x)
```

output :

```
{'operator': 'AND', 'negate': False, 'nodes': [{'operator': 'OR', 'negate': False, 'cpeMatch': [{'vulnerable': True, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:application_delivery_controller_firmware:10.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': 'D56F2AAF-4658-484C-9A3A-D8A52BA5B10C'}, {'vulnerable': True, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:application_delivery_controller_firmware:11.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': '8CE9E655-0D97-4DCF-AC2F-79DCD12770E5'}, {'vulnerable': True, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:application_delivery_controller_firmware:12.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': '49454F7D-77B5-46DF-B95C-312AF2E68EAD'}, {'vulnerable': True, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:application_delivery_controller_firmware:12.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': '201246D4-1E22-4F28-9683-D6A9FD0F7A6B'}, {'vulnerable': True, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:application_delivery_controller_firmware:13.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': 'A3A50966-5554-4919-B6CE-BD8F6FF991D8'}]}, {'operator': 'OR', 'negate': False, 'cpeMatch': [{'vulnerable': False, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:h:citrix:application_delivery_controller:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': '80E69E10-6F40-4FE4-9D84-F6C25EAB79D8'}]}]}

{'operator': 'AND', 'negate': False, 'nodes': [{'operator': 'OR', 'negate': False, 'cpeMatch': [{'vulnerable': True, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:netscaler_gateway_firmware:10.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': '7E0FA8E2-3E8F-481E-8C39-FB00A9739DFC'}, {'vulnerable': True, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:netscaler_gateway_firmware:11.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': 'A5D73B9A-59AA-4A38-AEAF-7EAB0965CD7E'}, {'vulnerable': True, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:netscaler_gateway_firmware:12.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': 'B9F3ED0E-7F3D-477B-B645-77DA5FC7F502'}, {'vulnerable': True, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:netscaler_gateway_firmware:12.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': '58349F8E-3177-413A-9CBE-BB454DCD31E4'}]}, {'operator': 'OR', 'negate': False, 'cpeMatch': [{'vulnerable': False, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:h:citrix:netscaler_gateway:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': 'DEBB9B6A-1CAD-4D82-9B1E-939921986053'}]}]}

{'operator': 'AND', 'negate': False, 'nodes': [{'operator': 'OR', 'negate': False, 'cpeMatch': [{'vulnerable': True, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:gateway_firmware:13.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': 'A80EAFB1-82DA-49BE-815D-D248624B442C'}]}, {'operator': 'OR', 'negate': False, 'cpeMatch': [{'vulnerable': False, 'criteria': 'cpe:2.3:h:citrix:gateway:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'matchCriteriaId': '3EF98B43-71DB-4230-B7AC-76EC2B1F0533'}]}]}
```

My procedure : I get the information, I transfer the output from "list" to string (I don't know if it's the best way) with the code above.

Then I delete the useless elements with a variable "to_delet_char = ["''", '""', "{" ,"}", "vulnerable", ": True, 'criteria': ", ", : ", "'", "]", ",", "OR negate:", "operator:", "False", "cpeMatch:", "[", "]", ]

And my goal would be to remove all the information other than "cpe" present in the outputs to have a result in the form of "list" or "dictionary" in which I will find only this kind of elements:

"cpe:2.3:o:citrix:netscaler_gateway_firmware:12.0:*:*:*:*:*:*"

I manage without difficulty to delete everything, however the Match serial ID being different each time I can't target it.

Would there be a solution via another library or not to "recover only" the cpe or to delete everything except the "cpe" and then transform them into a list or dictionary for the purpose of a database entry

Comment: If each node is a data structure it's counterproductive to stringify it. You could loop through the list with the key "nodes" in each element and for each entry loop through the list with the key "cpeMatch". Then you will only have to fetch the dictionary entry with the key "criteria".

Comment: At the end you don't remove anything but you build a new `list[dict]` with only the entries you're interested in.

Comment: @Matthias Thank you for your answer. 
I am still a beginner, I think I have well understood the theory however on the practice would you have an example or documentation on the subject because I do not know how to "navigate" in the list with a key or retrieve a dictionary entry with a key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your answers, I managed to make a mix of a bit of everything you sent me and here is the final code that allows me to list all the cpe

```
import nvdlib
import re

r = nvdlib.searchCVE(cveId='CVE-2019-19781')[0]

conf = r.configurations #output = list

for x in conf:
txt = ', '.join(str(x) for x in x.nodes) #transforme list to string

#loop string startwith cpe:2.3:
for match in re.finditer(r'cpe:2.3:', txt):
    print(txt[match.start():].split()[0][:-2])
```

Output :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgifC.png)

So everything works, I will find a solution to enter each element in a list or dictionary finally what will be the simplest for a future treatment

Answer (score 0):

Since the structure is an alternation of lists of dictionaries, gradually plunging into it, you can get the necessary elements.

```
import nvdlib

r = nvdlib.searchCVE(cveId='CVE-2019-19781')[0]

conf = r.configurations
cpes = []
for elem in conf:
    for el in elem.nodes:
        for e in el.cpeMatch:
            cpes.append(e.criteria)
print(cpes)

['cpe:2.3:o:citrix:application_delivery_controller_firmware:10.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:application_delivery_controller_firmware:11.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:application_delivery_controller_firmware:12.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:application_delivery_controller_firmware:12.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:application_delivery_controller_firmware:13.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:h:citrix:application_delivery_controller:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:netscaler_gateway_firmware:10.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:netscaler_gateway_firmware:11.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:netscaler_gateway_firmware:12.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:netscaler_gateway_firmware:12.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:h:citrix:netscaler_gateway:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:o:citrix:gateway_firmware:13.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*', 'cpe:2.3:h:citrix:gateway:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*']
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's quite hard to delete everything in the string because you can't foresee what's going to be inside the string in future. But then you can spot the pattern which is to find for the cpe substring.

Simply just add this, for every loop you look for the substring and then do some slicing, splitting and also trimming to get your final output.

```
nIndex = x.find('cpe')

print ((x[nIndex:].split())[0][:-2])
```

just an example with one line, it will give you the output below,

[image]

What I've shown you above is only for a single cpe substring within one iteration. Possibly you will have to find for a few within that iteration. You can refer to this good example on how to retrieve multiple index > https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873422/12128167

For the storing of data, the simplest way is to use a list which is simply done by declaring an empty `list=[]`, followed by appending it at the end `list.append("your output")`. You can explore other python collections if you intend to use them > https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: Thank you for your help, I slightly adapted your code to my purpose however I noticed that it only recovers the first "cpe" present in the output out it is possible that sometimes several cpe are present. 
The code : for x in conf:
    txt = ', '.join(str(x) for x in x.nodes)
    nIndex = txt.find('cpe:2.3:')
    print ((txt[nIndex:].split())[0][:-2])

Comment: @Vilguax if it works you can use it, I added a link in the answer because I noticed too that there are multiple "cpe"s. You can see if it helps you.